# Stripe- Send Payment to Customers

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I want to use STRIPE PHP API for creating payments to customers and for that i have found the code to create the customers but not for to create payment for them.

Code to create customers: 
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer

```
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php'); 
    Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_k9NE13Q2LjsIvYTNQHiP5C5H");
    Stripe_Customer::create(
     array( "description" => "Customer for test@example.com",
            "card" => "tok_1509ycG2gfbJDdl3oYWMe6yq" // obtained with Stripe.js
     ));
```

**My Scenario is** : I have some products and customers comes to my site and purchase the product but some of the customers will come from the affiliate banner and we need to pay some commission amount to the affiliate customers.

So, for such scenario i have to create customers and create payment for them and i have found PHP API code for creating the customers but not for the creating payment to that customers.

Comment: `creating payment to that customers` pretty sure stripe doesn't work like that.

Comment: Obvious thing is that I will take the card details or bank details of the affiliate user to create payment after creating them in Stripe system.

Comment: @Qix is right; this is not possible with Stripe, at least not now.

Comment: @EdCottrell , I'm assuming that if i can create the customer and pay them manually from my stripe Dashboard , so that can also be possible using API. In Reference to these thing I'm able to create the customer but not to create payment.

Comment: Stripe is for receiving payments, not making them. You can issue refunds or reduce the amount you charge your customers, but you can't make payments *to* people from your Stripe account. It's just not set up as an affiliate-payment network.

Comment: I want that if i create the customer on Stripe and Create payment for them, If you have stripe account then you can see it on https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/customers/

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your last comment means. Are you trying to create customers using the API and receive payments from them? Or are you trying to make payments from you to your "customers?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68137/discussion-between-harshal-mahajan-and-ed-cottrell).

Comment: Isn't that the wrong token? Shouldn't it be "ca..."?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I understand, you should use `Stripe managed accounts` for your customers to make `Payouts`.

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts

You'll need to collect additional customer verification data to make `payouts` to managed accounts:

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/updating-accounts#account-verification
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing-verification

Comment: Thank you Viktor! This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8):

I think your problem here is that you're misunderstanding the *customer* option in the stripe dashboard.

A typical use would be you register a customer and once you've done that you can **charge** their card as required, i.e., they are still sending you money, which I believe isn't what you want.

Two options I can see for you.

It's possible to transfer money from your Stipe account to a 3rd party bank account or credit card.  See [stripe transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers) and also this [FAQ](https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-pay-out-my-vendors-contractors-or-service-providers)

Alternatively there is a now [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect#payments) which might just be the ticket for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to create payment for users not to charge them.See the `My Scenario is` part of my question.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan , yeah sorry, my coffee hasn't kicked in ;)

Comment: Stripe Transfer will work only for US accounts, that would be problematic for me  and i think Stripe Transfer can get work for me but let me sure about this first. I'm also in contact with support of Stripe.