# Stripe- Send Payment to Customers [Alternates]

Tags: payment-method, payout, stripe-payments

As per this link, it is not possible with stripe to make payouts for customers.
[Stripe- Send Payment to Customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755663/stripe-send-payment-to-customers)

We are making a system like a lottery. We will collect payment from customers and then draw a customer from them, for payout.

If someone please helps me and share alternate approaches, which can work at least in Europe and USA regions.